# GeoJSON to vector tile in EPSG:4326 with Leaflet.vectorgrid

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, geojson, vector-tiles

*Goal*

Display a fairly large GeoJSON point dataset as vector tile in `Leaflet v1.7.1` with the `Leaflet.VectorGrid.js` plugin. Also, use the popup feature to display all properties.

*Code and input data source*

The [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9DiYdWoESZZkySVC?preview) link shows the full source code. The input GeoJSON file is available from [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgq5uf5ktm71v5j/earthquakes1970-2014.geojson?dl=0).

*Status*

After much effort and some tweaking of the `Leaflet.VectorGrid.js` plugin, it works very well for EPSG:3857 along with the desired popups and resizing of icons upon change of the zoom level.

*Question/Need help for:*

It does not work for EPSG:4326; the points are misplaced. The `projectPoint` function inside the `Leaflet.VectorGrid.js` plugin that converts map coordinates to image coordinates is not following the defined projection in the Leaflet map object. For EPSG:4326, I have tried a simple linear transform of latitude longitude to image coordinates (clamping to a range of 0 to 1), but that approach did not work as seen in the second image below.

*Result (EPSG:3857): Success*

[image]

*Result (EPSG:4326): Failure*
[image]

*Relevant part of the code*

```
    <script>
      var EPSG4326 = new L.Proj.CRS(
        'EPSG:4326',
        '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs',
        {
          origin: [-180, 90],
          resolutions: [
            0.5625,
            0.28125,
            0.140625,
            0.0703125,
            0.03515625,
            0.017578125,
            0.0087890625,
            0.00439453125,
            0.002197265625
          ],
          bounds: L.Bounds([
            [-180, -90],
            [180, 90]
          ])
        }
      )

      var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 1,
        maxZoom: 10,
        keyboard: false,
        zoomDelta: 1,
        crs: EPSG4326,
        maxBounds: [[-120, -220], [120, 220]]
      })

      // Add some tile layer in EPSG:4326, e.g., from NASA GIBS
      var nasagibs_static_epsg4326_template =
        '//gibs-{s}.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/' +
        '{layer}/default/{tileMatrixSet}/{z}/{y}/{x}.jpg'
      var nasagibs_static_epsg4326_template_option = {
        layer: 'BlueMarble_ShadedRelief_Bathymetry',
        maxNativeZoom: 6,
        tileMatrixSet: '500m',
        tileSize: 512,
        subdomains: 'abc',
        noWrap: true,
        continuousWorld: true,
        attribution: 'NASA GSFC GIBS',
        bounds: [
          [-89.9999, -179.9999],
          [89.9999, 179.9999]
        ]
      }

      var layer = L.tileLayer(
        nasagibs_static_epsg4326_template,
        nasagibs_static_epsg4326_template_option
      )
      map.addLayer(layer)

      /* test on epsg3857 works as intended
      var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2)
      L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 1,
        attribution:
          '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      }).addTo(map)
      */

      // Add a mouse location pointer
      ctlMouseposition = L.control
        .mousePosition({
          position: 'bottomright',
          lngFormatter: function (num1) {
            var num = num1 <= -180.0 ? -180.0 : num1 >= 180.0 ? 180.0 : num1
            var direction = num < 0 ? 'W' : 'E'
            var formatted =
              Math.abs(L.Util.formatNum(num, 2)) + '&#176; ' + direction
            return formatted
          },
          latFormatter: function (num1) {
            var num = num1 <= -90.0 ? -90.0 : num1 >= 90.0 ? 90.0 : num1
            var direction = num < 0 ? 'S' : 'N'
            var formatted =
              Math.abs(L.Util.formatNum(num, 2)) + '&#176; ' + direction
            return formatted
          }
        })
        .addTo(map)

      // Add a GeoJSON (points) data from a relatively large file
      // define a style
      var lyrStyle = function (properties, zoom) {
        return {
          icon: L.icon({
            iconUrl:
              'data:image/png;base64,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',
            iconSize: [2, 2],
            iconAnchor: [1, 1]
          })
        }
      }

      var geojsonFile = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgq5uf5ktm71v5j/earthquakes1970-2014.geojson?dl=0', vectorgrid;
      $.ajax({ url: geojsonFile }).done(function (d_init) {
        var lyr = JSON.parse(d_init)
        var style = {
          maxZoom: 10,
          rendererFactory: L.svg.tile, // L.canvas.tile
          zIndex: 301,
          vectorTileLayerStyles: {
            sliced: lyrStyle
          },
          indexMaxZoom: 2,
          interactive: true,
          getFeatureId: function (f) {
            return f.properties['EventID']
          }
        }

        vectorgrid = L.vectorGrid.slicer(lyr, style)
        vectorgrid.on('click', function (e) {
          var properties = e.layer.properties
          var popUpText = Object.entries(properties)
            .map(function ([key, val]) {
              return `${key}: ${val}`
            })
            .join('<br>')
          L.popup()
            .setContent(popUpText)
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .openOn(map)
        })
        vectorgrid.addTo(map)
      })

      // Update icon size based on zoom level
      map.on('zoomend', function (evt) {
        var zoom = map.getZoom()
        var pointIconSize = [1, 1].map(x => 2 * zoom)
        vectorgrid.options.vectorTileLayerStyles.sliced = () => {
          return {
            icon: L.icon({
              iconUrl:
                'data:image/png;base64,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',
              iconSize: pointIconSize,
              iconAnchor: pointIconSize.map(x => x / 2)
            })
          }
        }
        vectorgrid.redraw()
      })
    </script>
```

*Required tweak in the `Leaflet.VectorGrid.js plugin`*

```
    _createLayer: function(feat, pxPerExtent, layerStyle) {
        var layer;
        switch (feat.type) {
        case 1:
            layer = new PointSymbolizer(feat, pxPerExtent);
            layer.getLatLng = null; // Tweak: set to Null for Points
            break;
...
```

*Note*: The slightly modified plugin can also be downloaded from [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9DiYdWoESZZkySVC?preview). If you like, you may download the file `Leaflet.VectorGrid.js` from the Plunker link.

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code in the body of the question, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code. Besides that it would be very hard to do any debugging without knowing where and why you tweaked the plugin.

Comment: Thanks, @TomazicM, good point. I was somehow of the opinion from other comments that for full code it's better to use and link to sites like Plunker. Okay, will include some relevant parts here too. The code itself is simple, the issue is most likely related to missing CRS support in the Leaflet.VectorGrid.js plugin or related dependencies.
Tweak:
 _createLayer: function(feat, pxPerExtent, layerStyle) {
  var layer;
  switch (feat.type) {
  case 1:
   layer = new PointSymbolizer(feat, pxPerExtent);
            layer.getLatLng = null; // the tweak.
...

Comment: Please post the tweak in the body of the question so it's complete in itself and there is no need to go through comments to get all the necessary info.

Comment: Included the tweak at the bottom of the body of the question and also provided the link from where the modified plugin can be downloaded. I appreciate your time looking at this regardless of whether we can fix it or not.

Comment: I'm afraid you are out of luck with with `EPSG:4326`. A had a look at the plugin source code and it seems that vector tiles are fixed `EPSG:3857`, there is no transform done if map has different CRS. For example, I found the following comment in the code: _Transforms the coordinates of each feature in the given tile from mercator-projected space into (extent x extent) tile space._ I author of the plugin @IvanSanchez comes by, he might confirm this.

Comment: Thank you for putting your time and looking into this and confirming what I was beginning to get afraid of. It's a nice plugin, loads a large amount of data with amazing speed, and would be so useful to have more CRS compatibility. Let's see if @IvanSanchez will provide some more insight/solution.

Comment: What the heck have you guys done and why must I solve it.

Comment: `VectorGrid.Slicer` relies on `geojson-vt`, which is hard-coded for EPSG:3857, so that's gonna be a "nope".

Comment: See https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt/blob/35f4ad75feed64e80ff2cd02994976c6335859cd/src/convert.js#L130-L137 - you want to change how `geojson-vt` projects and tiles data, you've gotta put your projection & tiling logic in there.

Comment: okay, thanks for your attention & understood that it depends on `geojson-vt` settings, so you got nothing to do with this. I guess it's a dead-end then for now, & I'll explore alternatives. BTW, to your Q "What the heck have you guys done?", I tried modifying the function projectPoint(p) replacing this: `var sin = Math.sin(p[1] * Math.PI / 180),  x = (p[0] / 360 + 0.5),  y = (0.5 - 0.25 * Math.log((1 + sin) / (1 - sin)) / Math.PI)` with this: `var  x = (p[0] + 180) / 360, y = (p[1] - 90) / -180`, but this did not help. It was sensitive to the change but scaling was not appropriate.